# How to get HTML from JSON data, Using MUSTACHE?

Tags: php, json, mustache

I am using JSON and MUSTACHE, for templates in my new site. But I don't know how can i get the HTML out of json data. I am using PHP in backend, which is working as API provider. I am very new to this concept. Evey help and suggestions are Welcome.

Thanks.

Code I am using::

```
<script>
// this is for base
    this.get(/\#\/(.*)/, function (){
      var send_url = '<?php echo $url?>sammy/' + this.params['splat'];
      var context = this;
      $.getJSON(send_url, function(data) {
        var template = data.template;
        context.renderEach('<?php echo $url?>mustache_templates/' + template + '', data.data).swap();
      });
    });
</script>
```

JSON data is like::

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "string": "<a href=\"http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/5335873\/how-to-get-html-from-json-data-using-mustache#xyz\">string</a>",
}}
```

MUSTACHE template:

```
{{#string}}
<div>
{{string}}
</div>
{{/string}}
```

Current Output:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335873/how-to-get-html-from-json-data-using-mustache#xyz">string</a>
```

Output Needed:

[string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335873/how-to-get-html-from-json-data-using-mustache#xyz)

Thanks you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Current Output:
>
> ```
> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335873/how-to-get-html-from-json-data-using-mustache#xyz">string</a>
> ```

That is not the output. What you actually get is something like

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335873/how-to-get-html-from-json-data-using-mustache#xyz&quot;&gt;string&lt;/a&gt;
```

Which of course looks like what you've posted in a browser. Mustache HTML escapes all your variables by default, so they don't mess up your HTML.

In this case you don't want that, so you should use `{{{string}}}` in the template. Be sure to only do that with trusted variables, never use it to output any user input.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [json_decode](http://www.php.net/json_decode) in PHP, that'll get you an array of your data which you (i presume) can feed to your templating engine:

```
$json = <<< EOJ 
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "string": "<a href=\"http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/5335873\/how-to-get-html-from-json-data-using-mustache#xyz\">string</a>",
}}
EOJ;

$json_parsed = json_decode($json_raw, TRUE); // return an array, not an object

DoYourMustacheThingWith($json_parsed);
```

Comment: I am sorry, I think i was not able to explain it good, actually i am not passing back values to PHP, but getting value from it.. I have edited the Question for better Understanding.. Thanks for the reply.. looking forward for more help